# How to get last value(Date Sort or last row) from VLookup? (Google Sheet with multiple sheet)

Tags: google-sheets

How to get last value(Date Sort or last row) from VLookup on Google Sheet with multiple sheet ?

Please advice and help me the way to solve this problem.

*******This is google sheet*******
Sheet1 : [ALL STORE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c74cm4kpFRlCqPzUJHSwAaYA4ZEpsR0F5pzp5UXGNDQ/edit#gid=0) Click
Sheet2 : [Storage1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NM6Yc-Obc0OhjpoEVwSZ6ACourpAVdAwbVnxQeJ77Rg/edit#gid=0) Click

**Need get the last value from Sheet Storage1 To Sheet ALL STORE**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptXe0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NM6Yc-Obc0OhjpoEVwSZ6ACourpAVdAwbVnxQeJ77Rg/edit#gid=0","Storage1Sheet1!A2:D6"), "order by Col1 desc limit 1", 0)
```